# Firebase POST to Realtime Database adding an extra section

Tags: firebase, post, postman

I'm trying to upload data into Firebase Realtime Database I have tried first doing a POST through the API this is my Query:

Method: POST

EndPoint: https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/5Vzshkdlu8W3sDSZMt9bc9SyhiF8.json

- Note I'm using my Project ID

Headers: 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Body:

```
{
    "name": "Rene Alas",
    "correo": "[Email]",
    "image": "[URL to my Image]",
    "title": "Albo Aficionado",
    "acceso": 0
    }
```

I tried this on Postman but it gets me an additional part:

[image: Look into Firebase]

As you can see it added a middle part between my given ID and the Data which is Auto Assigned in this particular example:

*MTLim4FiFfdeZP4yPZP*

Any Ideas how I can put the information underneath the given ID so it doesn't auto assign that key?

Kind Regards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP semantics say that `POST` creates a new resource under the location, which is what Firebase does in your situation.

If you want to write a value you specify to the location and overwrite any existing data there, that'd be a call with the [`PUT` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-put).

If you want the data you pass (on a key by key basis) to be combined with data already at the location, use the `PATCH` method that Martin mentions.

Comment: So let me explain a bit before, the thing is that I'm trying to insert for the first time, the Document with the ID: 5Vzshkdlu8W3sDSZMt9bc9SyhiF8 doesn't exist just yet, so what I'm trying to get is to create the structure like this: 

`Users
-5Vzshkdlu8W3sDSZMt9bc9SyhiF8
- -name: Rene Alas
-- access: 0
-- correo:  myemail
-- title: Albo Aficionado`

Why do I need this, so when I search for it I search with the ID given. 

Any Ideas?

Comment: `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `POST` all create the path in the database if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Good Catch Sorry I just tried doing a Put and it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update that node, the HTTP request method is [`PATCH`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-patch) and not `POST`.

This can be used to update individual childs, see the examples.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to Update I'm creating a new one but with that ID

Comment: You could post to `/users.json` and get a key assigned.

Comment: So Martin the Problem is that the key I'm providing is the Local ID provided by Firebase Auth, so what I wish to do is to have a Collection (Table) where I can match additional User information for the currently Log User so when I'm creating the User on my App I want to add the User with the correct ID inside of this Collection.